# the_content getting current page content instead specified ID

Tags: filters, shortcode, the-content

I'm using below code to call the_content of a custom post type post, but when I'm run it, it always getting the current page content not the page whose ID specified. It literally duplicate my page whereever I use it. But it work perfectly when Used Via shortcode inside a post:

```
$id=12; 
$post = get_post($id); 
$content = apply_filters('the_content', $post->post_content); 
echo $content;
```

Getting this error:

```
Attempt to read property "post_content" on null
```

Comment: Is 12 definitely a post? Is `$id` always 12? If not, where are you getting `$id`?

Comment: I'm using this is a widget, which fetch id of post using dropdown, but that works fine.

Comment: Are you sure? You should echo the ID to make sure it’s correct. The error you’re receiving only makes sense if $id is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

Set postdata after get_post to set their data.

```
$id=12; 
$post = get_post($id); 
setup_postdata($post);
$content = apply_filters('the_content', $post->post_content); 
echo $content; 


wp_reset_postdata();
```